# Partition with offset and varying size

Tags: partitions

Assume I have the list below.

```
 list=Range@20;
```

Desired partition is:

> {{1,2,3,4},{4,5,6,7,8},{8,9,10,11,12},{12,13,14,15,16},{16,17,18,19,20}}

I have tried

```
Partition[Range@20, 4, 3]
```

and

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop, Range@20, Range[4, 6]]
```

does not give me what I want. Any suggestion?

Comment: What determines the size of the sublist?

Comment: I would like to overlap the end point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Partition[Range @ 20, 5, 4, {2, 2}, {}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {12, 13, 14, 15, 
>     16}, {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}}

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution:

```
Join[{Range@4}, Partition[Range[4, 20], 5, 4]]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {12, 13, 14, 15,
>   16}, {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}}

If there is other solution I would like to see them as well.